# Adding Offset to Address in C# results in different Address than in Cheat Engine

Tags: c#, memory, memory-address

I followed a tutorial on how to find offsets for a specific value of a game in Cheat Engine. I found the offset and now i want to read it in C#.

[image: This is the pointer im using]

"ac-client.exe" = 0x00400000

If i put the address in directly it gives the correct result, but if i calculate the address with the given offsets i get a different address.

The address i get is: 0x0057E0A8
Result according to Cheat Engine = 0x00856D70:
[image: Cheat Engine Path]

This is the Code:

```cs
Process gameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(process).FirstOrDefault();
IntPtr baseAddress = IntPtr.Add(gameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress, 0x17E0A8);
Console.WriteLine("Base Address: " + gameProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToString("X"));
Console.WriteLine("Local Address: " + baseAddress.ToString("X"));
```

The Base Address is correct (0x00400000) but the address after adding the offset is wrong.

[image: Console Output]

Am i doing something wrong? Im already trying for hours, this is driving me crazy.

I already tried different offsets and calculating the address manually (The result in the code is correct, but how does Cheat Engine get that address by adding that offset to the base address?).

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post to provide "expected" information as text? Also clarify why exactly you think the value you are getting is "wrong" (looks correct to me based on math).

Comment: What do you mean with "expected" information as text? (The Images?) And the reason why i think the value is wrong is because cheat engine shows a different address when adding the offset to the base address. Cheat Engine somehow got the address 0x00856E5C. But i manually calculated the address and got the same result as in my code. I just don't know how cheat engine got to that address.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the real question you have "I just don't know how cheat engine got to that address" is off-topic on SO. Programming part of the question will continue missing details on what/why you expect particular values till you find answer to how that "cheat engine" get the address.

Comment: I mean it shows how to get there ("ac-client.exe" + 0017E0A8) but the result in cheat engine is different to the result in my code thats why im confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, i finally got it after looking at other examples. The tutorial i looked was wrong and i didn't know i had to read the values of the address in each step.

The corrected code looks like this:
[image]